# I have a file that is about 10 million lines long (all 12 eye seeds in minecraft, 1 seed = 1 line), after the seed is the coordinate of the stronghold

Tags: notepad++, minecraft

6413620094584315518  -738  -2006

-413936538313701656  -1430  1102

3620336432578486732  2104  1490

-4117164134756492790  1039  -1188

6737480798666030867  -1667  -828

2308473619237951617  985  -1612

...

This file is in **notepad++**. The question is: how can I delete all the coordinates or the columns that contain the coordinates. So that only the seeds remain:

6413620094584315518

-413936538313701656

3620336432578486732

-4117164134756492790

6737480798666030867

2308473619237951617

Comment: I will try to shorten my title next time (Im new to this place). This file is a txt file. Thx for the advice anyway

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach using a regex find and replace:

```regex
Find:    ^(-?\d+).*$
Replace: $1
```

### Demo

The above regex simply matches the first positive/negative number on the line, and then replaces with just that one value.

Note: Make sure that DOT ALL mode is *disabled* in the replace dialog in Notepad++.

Comment: Can you confirm if search mode has to be set to regular expression? This is very interesting way!

Comment: Yes, the search mode should be in regex, but do _not_ enable "dot matches newline" as an option.

Answer (score 2):

### Regular Expression

In Notepad++ you can search by Regular Expression (known as regex), which, in a very simplified sense, lets you set rules for what should be found rather than just a particular piece of text to find.  In this case, you want to find everything after the first space on each line, and replace that with nothing (in other words, delete it).

We can start our expression with a literal space character  , because that's the first character you want to get rid of.  Then, we want to get rid of everything after that.  In regex, `.*` means "any number of any character," or in other words, "everything."  This gives us this expression:

```
 .*
```

### Notepad++

Now we need to use this expression in Notepad++.  With the file open in Notepad++, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.  The following dialog should appear:

[image: Find Dialog]

You want to replace text, so click the "Replace" tab.  The dialog box should now look like this:

[image: Replace Dialog]

Now you'll want to make sure the "Search Mode" is set to "Regular expression" mode and make sure the ". matches newline" box is unticked.

The reason we want to untick the ". matches newline" box is because we want the `.*` part of our expression to stop at the end of the line.  If `.` matches newlines, it'll just match the whole rest of the file after line 1, which defeats the purpose of what we're trying to do.

The "Search Mode" box should now look like this:

[image: Search Mode Box]

Now we can type in our regular expression in the "Find What" box and leave the "Replace With" box empty, like so:

[image: Entering the query]

Then go ahead and click the "Replace All" button on the right:

[image: Search/Replace Buttons]

You're all done!  The coordinates are now gone.  Remember to save the file.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative way is ....

Find: `(?!^)[- ].*`
Replace all: `empty`